# On KConsole (Centos) I can only do up to 50 pages up, and I need the console to retain more content

Tags: centos, console

At work, I'm using `KConsole` on *CentOS* that I do not know a lot.

When commands are displaying a lot of content, I have to do some page-up to retrieve what I need.

Sometimes I'm lucky : its just two pages away, but sometimes it's more than 50. And `KConsole` cannot go over 50 pages up in my configuration.

Can I increase how much I can navigate on the console ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your current profile and increase scrolling -> scrollback to either more lines or unlimited scrollback.